# Separate the rotational acceleration from the gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, acceleration

I tried to plot the magnetometer and accelerometer readings: Fig1 and Fig2, respectively. The readings were collected by rotating the sensors around x,y,z axes. As you can see, the mag readings (Fig1) draw three ellipses (each ellipse is from one rotation around one axis). However, the acc readings (Fig2) do not draw any ellipses. I think the accelerometer recorded not only the Earth's gravity but also the rotational acceleration of the sensor itself, didn't it? If yes, please show me how to separate the rotational acceleration from the gravity.

Edit:  some more details

1. THE EXPERIMENT: I used a box with a magnetometer and an accelerometer inside. I rotated it by hand. The whole experiment lasted about 20 seconds. I am not clear about what kind of magnetometer and accelerometer. I just took it from the lab. I did the experiment to understand more about sensors.
2. THE FIGURES: the red dots are the readings of sensors. Each point includes three components: [mag_x, mag_y, mag_z] in Fig1, and [acc_x, acc_y, acc_z] in Fig2. The blue one is the ellipsoid best fit to the red dots.
3. THE QUESTION: did the accelerometer record not only the Earth's gravity but also the rotational acceleration of the sensor itself? And, please show me how to separate the rotational acceleration from gravity.

[image]

[image]

Edit2: @Andrew
The readings when I hold in hand for 2 seconds (in red).
The blue one exactly is the ellipsoid in my question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it may help you get responses if you add some more details to your question. What is the goal of your experiment? What magnetometer and accelerometer did you use? What do the red dots mean in the plots? What is the blue ellipsoid in the plots? What magnetic field is the magnetometer reading? How were the instruments rotated (how fast? was it done by hand or with a machine?)? It is difficult to look at the plots without context and figure out what is going on.

Comment: 1) THE EXPERIMENT: I used a box with a magnetometer and an accelerometer inside. I rotated it by hand. The whole experiment lasted about 20 seconds. I am not clear about what kind of magnetometer and accelerometer. I just took it from the lab. I did the experiment to understand more about sensors.
2) THE FIGURES: the red dots are the readings of sensors. Each point includes three components: [mag_x, mag_y, mag_z] in Fig1, and [acc_x, acc_y, acc_z] in Fig2. The blue one is the ellipsoid best fit to the red dots.

Comment: 3) THE QUESTION: did the accelerometer record not only the Earth's gravity but also the rotational acceleration of the sensor itself? And, please show me how to separate the rotational acceleration from gravity.

Comment: I see. I can imagine that moving an acceleratometer by hand will be much more sensitive to random vibrations in your hand, compared to a magnetometer, which is measuring a very smooth field. It might be interesting to just hold the accelerometer in your hand without rotating it at all, and see how large the fluctuations are in the acceleration read out.